# How is this question about flatulence off topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4505/169) is not well written, and if read exactly as written may strike users as trivial.

However, what if it's not a frat-guy-joke kind of question? What if the person has Irritable Bowed Syndrome or worse, and has pain secondary to gas buildup in the colon? If you look a bit more deeply into the question, it's at least implied:

> The Internet is full of advice on how to prevent flatulence (e.g. diet changes), but no serious tips on how to get rid of gas once it's set in.

"Are there methods to expel gas when I am experiencing gas-related abdominal pain?" seems as on-topic on Health.SE as most other questions here, and infinitely more interesting than questions about masturbation, what the proper amount of milk (and if so, kind and fat content) in the diet should be, how much water people need to drink, and exactly when during the day they should drink it.

Some people express health concerns better than others. If you want to clean up the front page (or any page) so that it looks respectable, *edit the poorly phrased questions* and downvote and delete (not just close) the atrocious ones. But [if you don't know, please do not assume](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4451/169) (as one user did in this question.)

But lest the question be lost, how is [this question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4505/169) not about health?

Comment: Can't see the question as it's been deleted. I'm on a steady decline in motivation to even look through the questions.

Comment: @JohnP - As you were the moderator who closed it, perhaps you can venture an answer? Or undelete the question so the community can see it? Or something?